# Rewrite joint probability as product of marginals when all the probabilities are $1$ or $0$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

I have a question about the possibility of rewriting a joint probability as the product of the marginals when all the probabilities can only take value $1$ or $0$. I start with introducing some notation and then I present the question more formally.

Let $G\equiv (G_1,G_2)$ be a $2\times 1$ random vector with finite support $Supp_G\equiv Supp_{G_1}\times Supp_{G_1}\equiv \{3,4\}\times \{5,6\}$, where "$\times$" denotes the Cartesian product operator.

Let $X\equiv (X_1,X_2)$ be a $2\times 1$ random vector with support $Supp_X\equiv Supp_{X_1}\times Supp_{X_1}$.

Let $\mathcal{V}_1$ be the collection of all possible functions $f_1: Supp_{X_1} \rightarrow Supp_{G_1}$. 
Let $\mathcal{V}_2$ be the collection of all possible functions $f_2: Supp_{X_2} \rightarrow Supp_{G_2}$.

Let $Y_1$ be a random variable with support $\mathcal{V}_1$. Let  $Y_2$ be a random variable with support $\mathcal{V}_1$. [Sorry, here I may need to use stochastic processes rather than random variables, but I'm not an expert].

All these random terms are defined on the same probability space.

Take $x_1\in Supp_{X_1}$, $x_2\in Supp_{X_2}$, $f_1\in \mathcal{V}_1$, and $f_2\in \mathcal{V}_2$.

Consider the probabilities
$$
Pr(G_1=3, G_2=4|X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, Y_1=f_1, Y_2=f_2)
$$
$$
Pr(G_1=3|X_1=x_1, Y_1=f_1)
$$
$$
Pr(G_2=4|X_2=x_2, Y_2=f_2)
$$

Given the construction above, I believe that each of these probabilities can be $1$ or $0$, i.e., cannot take a value in $(0,1)$.

**Question:** Does this imply (and why yes or no) that 
$$
Pr(G_1=3, G_2=4|X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2, Y_1=f_1, Y_2=f_2)=\\
Pr(G_1=3|X_1=x_1, Y_1=f_1)\times Pr(G_2=4|X_2=x_2, Y_2=f_2)
$$

Comment: Why do you want to "rewrite" it? If probability of something happening is zero, then probability of it happening together with other thing is zero as well. The formula works correctly for 0 & 1s, everything else would not.

Comment: 1) For reasons too long to explain I prefer the product of the marginals. 2) I didn't get from your comment if the formula works in my specific case or not. Thanks